# Create files/folder inside build system (maven/gradle) generated directories independent of the underlying build system

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have created a custom annotation library using maven as a build system and what that library does is it creates a set of files inside the target directory of the project using maven as a build system and I would Iike to extend the same to the gradle build system i.e. the same library should create files inside build directory of the project using gradle as a build system.

So my question is how can I do this? Is there any way I can know the build system in java ? Or is there any alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a gradle project from the existing maven project you've created.

In the directory containing your POM, run `gradle init` and gradle should generate a `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` that replicate your project in gradle form.

For reference [Automated Conversion](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/#automated_conversion)